# Issue calling parameters from other methods back into main method for final computations and output

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with calling my methods in place and redirecting them to the desired output.

*DESIRED FINAL OUTPUT*

WEIGHT CONVERSION

**1.** Pounds to kilograms

**2.** Kilograms to pounds

Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: **1**

Please enter the pounds: 50

***50*** pounds is ***22.6796*** kilograms.

(This is partial code, but if somebody can assist me to figure out this issue I will be able to do the rest).

Basically, in the 'desired final output' statement where it says: *xx pounds is xx.xxxx kilograms* I'm having trouble calling my other methods to do the final calculation in line 57.

```
 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare variables
    double nInitialPounds = 0;
    double nInitialKilos = 0.0;
    int nWeightSelection = 0;
    double dInitialWeight = 0.0;
    double dFinalWeight = 0.0;
    double nPoundsToKilos = 0.0;
    double nKilosToPounds = 0.0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    //Display program title
    System.out.println("WEIGHT CONVERSION");

    //Display program option selections
    System.out.println("1. Pounds to kilograms");

    System.out.println("2. Kilograms to pounds");

    //Print blank line to console
    System.out.println("");

    //Prompt user to make selection of desired output
    System.out.println("Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: ");

    //Read selection by user
    nWeightSelection = input.nextInt();


   //Begin while-loop statement
while (nWeightSelection == 1) {

    //Prompt user to enter the amount of weight to be converted
    System.out.print("Please enter the pounds: ");

    // Read number entered by the user
    dInitialWeight = input.nextDouble();

    //Call weight conversion for Pounds to Kilos
    nPoundsToKilos = poundsToKilos(nInitialKilos, dInitialWeight);

    //Print final weight
    System.out.println(+dInitialWeight + " pounds is " + nPoundsToKilos + " kilograms.");

    break;
}

} //end Main method

/**
 * This method converts weight in pounds to kilograms
 * @param nPounds       beginning weight in pounds
 * @param nKilos        desired output into kilograms
 * @return nFinalWeight     final weight in desired output
 */
public static double poundsToKilos(double nKilos, double nPounds) {
    //Declare variables
    double dFinalWeight = 0.0;                    //Final weight conversion from pounds to kilos

    //Calculate weight conversion
    dFinalWeight = (nPounds*2.204);

    return dFinalWeight;

} //end method poundsToKilos

/**
 * This method prints the converted weight to the console
 * @param nPounds       beginning weight in pounds
 * @param nKilos        desired output into kilograms
 * @return nFinalWeight     final weight in desired output
 */
public static double printWeight(double nKilos, double nPounds) {
    //Declare variables
    double dFinalWeight = 0.0;                    //Final weight conversion

    return dFinalWeight;

} //end method printWeight
```

Comment: You print it before you call the method. I don't understand the issue.

Comment: Your problem is that you always print `50 pounds is 0.0 kilograms.`?

Comment: @Laf exactly, I can't call the method to input the conversion properly.. What edits would you suggest?

Comment: See DHT's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 /**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Declare variables
    double nInitialPounds = 0;
    double nInitialKilos = 0.0;
    int nWeightSelection = 0;
    double dInitialWeight = 0.0;
    double dFinalWeight = 0.0;
    double nPoundsToKilos = 0.0;
    double nKilosToPounds = 0.0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Display program title
    System.out.println("WEIGHT CONVERSION");

    //Display program option selections
    System.out.println("1. Pounds to kilograms");

    System.out.println("2. Kilograms to pounds");

    //Print blank line to console
    System.out.println("");

    //Prompt user to make selection of desired output
    System.out.println("Please select the type of conversion you would like to make: ");

    //Read selection by user
    nWeightSelection = input.nextInt();


    //Begin while-loop statement
    while (nWeightSelection == 1) {
        //Prompt user to enter the amount of weight to be converted
        System.out.print("Please enter the pounds: ");

        // Read number entered by the user
        dInitialWeight = input.nextDouble();

        //Call weight conversion for Pounds to Kilos
        nPoundsToKilos = poundsToKilos(nInitialKilos, dInitialWeight);

        //Print final weight
        System.out.println(+dInitialWeight + " pounds is " + nPoundsToKilos + " kilograms.");

        break;
    }

    //Call weight conversion for Pounds to Kilos
    //nPoundsToKilos = poundsToKilos(nInitialKilos, nInitialPounds);

    //Call weight conversion for Kilos to Pounds
    nKilosToPounds = kilosToPounds(nInitialPounds, nInitialKilos);

} //end Main method

/**
 * This method converts weight in pounds to kilograms
 *
 * @param nPounds beginning weight in pounds
 * @param nKilos desired output into kilograms
 * @return nFinalWeight final weight in desired output
 */
public static double poundsToKilos(double nKilos, double nPounds) {
    //Declare variables
    double dFinalWeight = 0.0;                    //Final weight conversion from pounds to kilos

    //Calculate weight conversion
    dFinalWeight = nPounds * 2.204;

    return dFinalWeight;

} //end method poundsToKilos

/**
 * This method prints the converted weight to the console
 *
 * @param nPounds beginning weight in pounds
 * @param nKilos desired output into kilograms
 * @return nFinalWeight final weight in desired output
 */
public static double printWeight(double nKilos, double nPounds) {
    //Declare variables
    double dFinalWeight = 0.0;                    //Final weight conversion

    return dFinalWeight;

} //end method printWeight
```

Comment: Tried this @Magicano but it still gives the result conversion as 0.0? It's not pulling the nPoundsToKilos method properly.

Comment: It's still printing 0.0? Do I have to call it from the print statement at the bottom as opposed to the poundsToKilos conversion method?

Comment: It worked marvelously! I think my issue was the actual print statement I was outputting wasn't referencing the methods properly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are too many comments in this code, this makes it extremely difficult to read. You have descriptive variable names, a comment repeating the same information is redundant.

In programming, the sequence in which you perform operations is important. In this instance, you print out the final weight before you actually obtain it. A good IDE would have warned you that nPoundsToKilos was unused.

Swap

```
//Print final weight
System.out.println(dInitialWeight + " pounds is "  + nPoundsToKilos + " kilograms.");

//Call weight conversion for Pounds to Kilos
nPoundsToKilos = poundsToKilos(nInitialKilos, nInitialPounds);
```

To

```
//Call weight conversion for Pounds to Kilos
nPoundsToKilos = poundsToKilos(nInitialKilos, nInitialPounds);

//Print final weight
System.out.println( + dInitialWeight + " pounds is "  + nPoundsToKilos + " kilograms.");
```

Comment: `nPoundsToKilos` is initialized, so the compiler won't give a warning. And the warning would be that the variable isn't initialized, not that it is not used.